# How to serialize byte[] as simple JSON Array and not as base64 in JSON.net?

Tags: javascript, serialization, arrays, json.net

I use JSON.net to serialize some objects between C# and JavaScript. The JSON data is transfered via WebSocket between the .NET and browser application.

In the data structure there are some `byte[]` fields, I want these fields as an `Array` in JavaScript also.

How can I serialize a C# `byte[]` to a simple JSON Array like `[ 0 , 1 , 254, 255 ]` instead of a base64 string?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of is to convert the byte array into an integer array, like:

```
var intArray = byteArray.Select(b => (int)b).ToArray();
```

This wouldn't require any special handling of the JSON library, or any custom serialization or anything like that.

**EDIT**: This would mean having to customize your data object to handle the different type. Maybe:

```
public class CustomFoo : Foo
{
    // SomeBytesHere is a byte[] in the base class
    public new int[] SomeBytesHere { get;set; }
}
```

So maybe it's not the simplest - depending on how much stuff you have to serialize

Comment: I love the 'int Array' solution. Work's great and simple to implement. Many thank's for that hint.

Comment: Bravo. A byte fits into an int, and the whole int[] is an array of bytes. WCF with a JSON binding on the other end can take a JSON serialized DTO with a byte[] property and safely deserialize it without any custom formatters or base64 decode/Stream writing.
The size of the serialized JSON is pretty magnificent, but it works!

Comment: It will use 8 times the memory of the byte array though, so not always a viable solution.

Answer (score 71):

JSON.NET is selecting the `BinaryConverter` to read and write an array of bytes. You can see in [the source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/92d170a0783bc962f52faf02acfcecbe21d3b683/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/BinaryConverter.cs#L64) that it uses the `WriteValue` operation on the `JsonWriter` class with the array of bytes which causes them to be written to as Base-64.

To modify this, you can write your own converter which reads and writes an array in the format you expect:

```
public class ByteArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer,
        object value,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }

        byte[] data = (byte[])value;

        // Compose an array.
        writer.WriteStartArray();

        for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(data[i]);
        }

        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType,
        object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            var byteList = new List<byte>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.TokenType)
                {
                    case JsonToken.Integer:
                        byteList.Add(Convert.ToByte(reader.Value));
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.EndArray:
                        return byteList.ToArray();
                    case JsonToken.Comment:
                        // skip
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new Exception(
                        string.Format(
                            "Unexpected token when reading bytes: {0}",
                            reader.TokenType));
                }
            }

            throw new Exception("Unexpected end when reading bytes.");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(
                string.Format(
                    "Unexpected token parsing binary. "
                    + "Expected StartArray, got {0}.",
                    reader.TokenType));
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(byte[]);
    }
}
```

You would use this by applying the `JsonConverterAttribute` to the member:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ByteArrayConverter))]
public byte[] Data { get; set; }
```

Comment: Bonus points for providing the actual ByteArrayConverter class! However, there is a small error. Because you're already using a JsonWriter, there is no need to add the comma's manually, so you can just remove this part: 
if(i != data.Length)
{
    writer.WriteRaw(",");
}
Otherwise your array will look like this: [12,,54,,32,,8]

Comment: This works well and seems to be the way the json interface was meant to be used.

Comment: Excellent answer

Answer (score 1):

Ref [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52270189/2430943), JSON.net can customze serialization in setting for all instead of attribute in property.

You can easily change it from base64 to number array, just write a square bracketed csv raw value.