# MapEditor export as JSON - Object encrypted?

Tags: java, json, slick, tiled

I have used MapEditor for my choice of map creation with my particular TileMaps that i have made. My question is this:

When exporting a created map VIA JSON, Usually it seems most map's are shown as their tile id as shown in the snippet below.

```
{
  "data":[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1], <------ TIle Id's
  "height":4,
  "name":"ground",
  "opacity":1,
  "properties":
     {
      "tileLayerProp":"1"
     },
  "type":"tilelayer",
  "visible":true,
  "width":4,
  "x":0,
  "y":0
}
```

however, when i check my own exported JSON map in the same fields i see,

```
 {
         "compression":"zlib",
         "data":"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",
         "encoding":"base64",
         "height":100,
         "name":"solids",
         "opacity":1,
         "type":"tilelayer",
         "visible":true,
         "width":100,
         "x":0,
         "y":0
        },
```

both of these are real samples, the first pulled from their documentation and the second from my raw export. As you can see the 'data' field of theirs differs from mine in that theirs is a JSONArray and as a result I believe this function,

```
public static void load(String path) throws Exception 
    {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(path));
        JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) obj;

        JSONArray layers = (JSONArray) jObj.get("layers");
        int amount = layers.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) 
        {

            JSONObject layer = (JSONObject) layers.get(i);
            String type = (String) layer.get("name");

            if (type.equals("solids")) 
            {
                WIDTH = (int) ((long)layer.get("width"));
                HEIGHT = (int) ((long)layer.get("height"));
                solids = parse((JSONArray) layer.get("data"));
            }
```

has been giving me problems. Is it because in the 'data' field of my map, i believe that is a JSONString and an encoded one at that.

After reasearching it seems I would need to decode the 'data' and somehow eventually that will turn into the 'data' field you see in the first block of code.

Any tips on how i might do this or JUST DISABLE ENCODING ALL TOGETHER?

EDIT: MY PARSE FUNCTION UPON REQUEST

```
private static Image[][] parse(JSONArray array)
    {
        Image[][] layer = new Image[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
        int index;

        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y)
            {
                index = (int)((long)array.get((y * WIDTH) + x)); //must cast because JSON returns long
                layer[x][y] = getSpriteImage(index);
            }
        }
        return layer;
    }
```

EDIT 2: my editted load function

```
public static void load(String path) throws Exception 
    {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(path));
        JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) obj;

        JSONArray layers = (JSONArray) jObj.get("layers");
        int amount = layers.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) 
        {

            JSONObject layer = (JSONObject) layers.get(i);
            String type = (String) layer.get("name");

            if (type.equals("solids")) 
            {
                Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
                byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decode((byte[]) layer.get("data"));
                Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
                solids = parse((JSONArray)decompresser.inflate(decodedBytes));
```

EDIT 3: my getSpriteImage function

```
private static Image getSpriteImage(int index)
{
    if (index == 0 )
    {
        return null;
    }

    index -= 1;

    SpriteSheet sheet = Resources.getSprite("tileset");
    int verti = sheet.getVerticalCount();
    int horiz = sheet.getHorizontalCount();

    int y = (index / verti);
    int x = (index % horiz);

    return sheet.getSubImage(x, y);
}
```

EDIT 5: how the map looks

```
[44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, etcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc]
```

EDIT 6: RENDER Method for World & GameState

world-  the final value of Tile.SIZE = 5;

```
public static void render(float xRend, float yRend)
    {
        int offset = 2;
        int xStart = (int)(xRend / Tile.SIZE) - offset;
        int yStart = (int)(yRend / Tile.SIZE) - offset;
        int xEnd = (Window.WIDTH / Tile.SIZE) + xStart + (offset * 2);
        int yEnd = (Window.HEIGHT / Tile.SIZE) + yStart + (offset * 2);

        for (int x = xStart; x < xEnd; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = yStart; y < yEnd; ++y)
            {
                if (solidTileBound(x, y))
                {
                    solids[x][y].draw(x * Tile.SIZE, y * Tile.SIZE, Tile.SIZE, Tile.SIZE);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

and GameState:

```
@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame stateGame, Graphics gfx) throws SlickException 
{
    gfx.drawString(("Game State"), 50, 50);

    //gfx.translate(-1500, -1500);
    World.render(500, 500);
    //gfx.resetTransform();

}
```

EDIT 7:

```
[LOG] Loading C:\Users\William.William-PC\Desktop\testMap.json
Sun Dec 06 18:51:33 EST 2015 ERROR:Error loading World
org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Error loading World
    at main.java.TestGame.init(TestGame.java:39)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:390)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:314)
    at main.java.Main.main(Main.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found: tileset.png
    at org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(ResourceLoader.java:69)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:169)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:196)
    at org.newdawn.slick.SpriteSheet.<init>(SpriteSheet.java:129)
    at org.newdawn.slick.SpriteSheet.<init>(SpriteSheet.java:115)
    at org.newdawn.slick.SpriteSheet.<init>(SpriteSheet.java:102)
    at main.java.Resources.addTileSet(Resources.java:55)
    at main.java.JSONLoader.load(JSONLoader.java:33)
    at main.java.TestGame.init(TestGame.java:31)
    ... 3 more
```

I looked through it thoroughly and I'm no sure where i'm supposed to be putting tileset.png or why the world won't load for that matter. Did you create your own .json export of a world to test this?

Comment: That second `data` field is [base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) encoded.

Comment: I see that, but further on in my question, I ask how might someone decode it or maybe just disable the encoding on export somehow? I am using mapeditor

Comment: It decodes to 382 bytes of binary data, which turns out to be [the default encoding for a `byte[]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226921/how-to-serialize-byte-as-simple-json-array-and-not-as-base64-in-json-net).

Comment: I find that link to be a little confusing for me in what i'm attempting. I tried adding this bit of code, am I on the right track? `Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
    byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decode((byte[]) layer.get("data"));`

Comment: Yes, that should work just fine. How exactly are you exporting the JSON? Perhaps the default encoding can be overriden there.

Comment: thats what i was hoping for. I am exporting it to JSON via MapEditor which is a tile based map maker. When i replace `solids = parse((JSONArray) layer.get("data"));` with `solids = parse((JSONArray)decodedBytes);` i get a now very similar to my previous error, `cannot cast byte[] to JSONArray`

Comment: You don't have to treat it as JSON anymore - it was already decoded from a JSON String, via base64, into a `byte[]`. That `parse` function, what does it do? Could you add it to the question?

Comment: @Kenney There you go my friend, i added it. parse is used with my images and sprite handling

Comment: Thanks; you're going to have to change `parse(JSONArray)` to `parse(byte[])`. Btw, how are you exporting? Using this (https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/JSON-Map-Format)?

Comment: yes @githubLink that is the format i'm using. I'm tinkering with it still, not luck

Comment: I missed the `"compression":"zlib"`; I tried to decompress it and I got a long list of `,`, some sequences of `6`, one of `4`, and some `=` and `?` (40000 chars total), but in the end a CRC/length error. You're also going to need [zlib `Deflater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html).

Comment: I have edited my question with my updated `load` method, Am i getting any closer? I have never worked with either of these functionalities. I know I need to change what the parse functions parameter is, but when i do, i can no longer use the `JSONArray.get(int)` method inside my parse function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very close. Unfortunately `Inflater` is more complicated than that:

Instead of

```
            Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
            byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decode((byte[]) layer.get("data"));
            Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
            solids = parse((JSONArray)decompresser.inflate(decodedBytes));
```

try this:

```
            Object o = layer.get("data");

            if ( o instanceof JSONArray )
                solids = parseJSONArray( (JSONArray) o );
            else if ( o instanceof String 
                && "base64".equals( layer.get( "encoding" ) )
                && "zlib".equals( layer.get( "compression" ) )
            )
            {
                // base64 decode
                Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
                byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decode((String) o);

                // zlib decompress
                Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
                decompresser.setInput(decodedBytes);
                byte[] decompressedBytes = new byte[WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4];
                int resultLength = decompresser.inflate(decompressedBytes);
                decompresser.end();

                // convert `byte[N*4]` to `int[N]`
                int[] result = new int[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(decompressedBytes);
                bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                bb.asIntBuffer().get(result);

                solids = parseIntArray( result );
            }
            else
                throw new RuntimeException( "Unimplemented data type: "
                    + o.getClass().getName() );
```

Rename your original `parse` function to `parseJSONArray` (for instance),
then copy it to a new function `parseByteArray` like this:

```
private static Image[][] parseIntArray( int[] array )
{
    Image[][] layer = new Image[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

    for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
        for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y)
            layer[x][y] = getSpriteImage( array[ y * WIDTH + x ] );

    return layer;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to assume in the "try this:" you intended on all instances of decompresser/or to be spelled the same?

Comment: Was just double checking it wasn't a keywork or something! So once i adjusted everything and re-ran my Engine, `World.load("res/maps/world.json");` I get an error on my line while decoding, `Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
    byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decode((byte[]) layer.get("data"));` gives me a similar error, `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [B
 at world.World.load(World.java:61)`

Comment: Ah I accidently removed that -yes, there's a problem there too: `decoder.decode( layer.get("data") )` transforms `String` to `byte[]`. Updated, hope it works now.

Comment: Hm.. I'm stilling getting an error on line `byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decode(layer.get("data"));` it says `The method decode(byte[]) in the type Base64.Decoder is not applicable for the arguments (Object)`. It seems we're passing decode an Object it doesn't like?

Comment: Updated with runtime checking; it should now support both JSONArray and String and throw an exception if it is something else.

Comment: in the first `if` statement, what is the value of `solids = parseJSONArray( (JSONArray) result );`'s result? i see that in the next elseif statement you declare what result is. I'm getting an error because of it. Should i declare `byte[] result;` at the top, below `o`?

Comment: It's not my day, apparently ;-) Updated again - `result` should've been `o`.

Comment: yes!!! `try {
   World.load("res/maps/world.json");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("can't load world");` finally workeddddddd!! we did it Kenney. Thanks a ton for sticking through this with me. I had never messed with either of these utilities in java :)

Comment: I hope it didn't print `"can't load world"`? :-)

Comment: yeah hehe not this time! :P

Comment: ah shoot haha @Kenney It compiles and seems to load the world sucsessfully but i'm not able to display it by the looks.. when you decompressed it and decoded it did you see what it looked like? something like data:"[44, 44, 44, 44, 42, 42,44,44] etc but really long?

Comment: Yes indeed, `40000` characters: looks like a map. I assumed it was a `byte[]` because it showed ASCII. But, now that I look at it, the `width` and `height` are both `100`, so the entire data is `10000` entries. That means they are indeed 32 bit integers (with weird values though). Updated the code again, to convert it to an int array.

Comment: on the line, `ByteBuffer.wrap( result.length ).asIntBuffer().get( result );` I'm getting an error. It seems ByteBuffer only takes a byte array `ByteBuffer.wrap(byte[] arr)` and we're giving it the length of an int array? error aside, could you explain this line? here is my error `The method wrap(byte[]) in the type ByteBuffer is not applicable for the arguments (int)` I have made all other changes, once i figure this out i can test to see if that helped with my rendering issue

Comment: You bet. Updated - should've been `ByteBuffer.wrap( decompressedBytes )`. It's that tiny textarea! :-)

Comment: unfortunately still no luck in regards to rendering it and it actually being displayed. :(

Comment: What kind of values does `getSpriteImage` have to work with?

Comment: I updated my question with my getSpriteImage function. The values getSpriteImage takes a parameter is an `int index`

Comment: What values do `verti` and `horiz` have? How many tiles are there? Maybe you should export as TMX too, and see what the corresponding values are there, then we can figure out what the data really is... From what I've found, TMX is pretty wel supported. So far it makes no sense, the id's would be 0x44444444 which means the tileset resource must be huge. What does the map look like? I added two of many possibilities of what the top might look like.

Comment: verti is the veritcal count of the sprite sheet. so the # of sprite on the x. and hori is the horizontal count of the sprite sheet so the # sprite on the y and i updated my question on how the map now looks that i've fixed the decoded/decompressed issue

Comment: I (finally) ran the code in Eclipse and found the problem: the data is `[ 0x44,0,0,0,  0x44,0,0,0, ....]` (I checked it with Perl before but the `0` weren't printed). ByteBuffer is big-endian by default (even on a little endian machine). I updated the code, added a `bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);`. It is now properly converted to 100x100 ints with reasonable values. I think it should work now!

Comment: Wow.. such complicated java i never thought i was getting into! haha Yes this works with no errors, and it doesn't set off the catch of my `trycatch` so thats good. Now i'm just having real problems rendering the map. I have attached my `render()` method to my question, for some reason i can not exceed `World.render(500, 500)` any idea why?

Comment: I reproduced your project locally and got it to work. I'll make a github repo and post the code there. I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks, appreicate it! just let me know and ill have a look

Comment: [Here you go](https://github.com/neonics/tiled-slick-starter-kit/tree/master/src/main/java).

Comment: What is this actually supposed to be doing? After fixing all the imports and getting the library paths right. Now i'm just getting a handful of errors, the main one being that when fileChooser comes up and i select the .json file from my Desktop, it immediately closes afterwards stating giving me the 'ol Error loading world. I've updated my question with the full error report. @Kenney

Comment: Hm, it's working fine here. The imports are perfect. I downloaded slick from http://slick.ninjacave.com/, and JSON-simple (which you seemed to be using) from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1. Tileset not found means that the file doesn't exist. I think I know what it is - paths relative to the file.

Comment: [Pushed a change](https://github.com/neonics/tiled-slick-starter-kit/commit/afa934595ec3e12d70ba3c6a5d2aea4f9a0c1c22). Should work for that file too.

Comment: ah interesting, so it loads the map successfully and pan's around. This is great. So from here, if i want to do something like, `Image hero = new Image("res/hero.png");` which class would be best to put it in? or should i just make a new one altogether with its own render, init, and update? In a perfect work i would like to get collision working with the player with just simple jumping obstacles . Any tips?

Comment: I'd play around with the Tile Editor a bit - there's an `Object` layer that you may be able to use. The `hero` can also come from a spritemap. But, yes, your `new Image("res/hero.png")` would work too, and your approach is good - a new class. You'd end up with `World.init(); Hero.init();` in the `TestGame.init()`, and likewise `World.render(..); Hero.render(..);` in the `TestGame.render`. Lots of design options! Also read the code and note the changes to your code: tiles and their ID's are handled automatically, for instance, you can have multiple layers, and I rewrote the `World.render`.