# Newtonsoft JSON serialization for byte[] property

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, json.net

```
public class MyClass
{
   public byte[] Bytes{get;set;}
}

MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.Bytes = new byte[]{1,22,44,55};

string s_result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

// my s_result looks like {"Bytes":"KQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="}
```

I want result like "Bytes":"1,22,44,55"

I did work around for this by creating one more int[] property in class like

```
 public class MyClass
    {
       [JsonIgnore]
       public byte[] Bytes{get;set;}
       public int[] MessageByte
        {
            get
            {
              if (this.Bytes == null)
                return null;
                int[] result = new int[this.Bytes.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < this.Bytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    result[i] = this.Bytes[i];
                }
                return result;
            }
        }

    }
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: [According to the docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#PrimitiveTypes), by default, a byte[] is serialized as a base64 encoded String.  Your workaround seems reasonable, but you could easily just make a one line LINQ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#PrimitiveTypes) it is declared that a `Byte[]` will be serialized as a Base64 encoded string.  So it is working as intended.

However you need an array of numbers.  I assume that you cannot simply change the `byte[]` to an `int[]` right?

Your work-around is actually the proper way of handling it, you can reduce the logic down a bit if you are interested (and using C#6 or above):

```
public int[] MessageBytes => Bytes?.Select(x => (int)x).ToArray() ?? new int[0];
```

This will "short circuit" if Bytes is null, and return an empty int array, if Bytes is not null, it will cast all the bytes to an int and then make that an array.

DotNetFiddle does not allow nuget packages in Roslyn compilers, so I cannot demonstrate the serialization. However [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GChc8J) demonstrates the LINQ logic I just showed.

**EDIT**

I think the linked duplicate has a [much better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15228384/2457029) than just doing a `int[]`, try looking into that before resorting to an int array.