# Newtonsoft C# Custom JsonConverter not deserializing an Array of Bytes

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to create a simple JsonConverter. I want my byte arrays to be serialized as an array of numbers instead of the default base 64 string. However, I'm getting an JsonSerializationException when I'm trying to do that.

Here's a class I made to simplify my problem:

```
public class SomethingFancy
{
    string name;
    byte[] usefulData;

    public SomethingFancy(string name, byte[] usefulData)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.UsefulData = usefulData;
    }

    public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
    public byte[] UsefulData { get => usefulData; set => usefulData = value; }
}
```

Now here's is my custom Json Converter. I tried to make it work only with IEnumerable objects. (by default, IEnumerable is converted to a string when serializing and viceversa when deserializing. I changed that behavior to save the IEnumerable as a json array of numbers instead.

```
public class EnumerableByteConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        var result = typeof(IEnumerable<byte>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(value);
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] bytes = ((IEnumerable<byte>)value).ToArray();
            int[] ints = Array.ConvertAll(bytes, c => (int)c);

            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (int number in ints)
            {
                writer.WriteValue(number);
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        int[] ints = (int[])reader.Value;
        if (ints == null)
            return default;
        else
        {
            byte[] bytes = ints.SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes).ToArray();
            if (objectType == typeof(byte[]))
            {
                return bytes;
            }
            var result = new List<byte>(bytes);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's some Unit test I wrote to test my class:

```
[TestClass]
public class PersistencyServiceTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestJsonSerializationDeserialization()
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add(new EnumerableByteConverter());

        SomethingFancy something = new SomethingFancy("someName", new byte[3] { 1, 2, 3 });

        string dataasstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(something, Formatting.Indented, settings);

        something = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomethingFancy>(dataasstring, settings);

        Assert.IsTrue(something != null);
        Assert.IsTrue(something.Name == "someName");
        Assert.IsTrue(something.UsefulData != null);
        Assert.IsTrue(something.UsefulData[0] == 1);
        Assert.IsTrue(something.UsefulData[1] == 2);
        Assert.IsTrue(something.UsefulData[2] == 3);
    }
}
```

Now, it serializes my object just as I needed.

```
{
  "Name": "someName",
  "UsefulData": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

However, the deserialization is throwing a JsonSerializationException (Unexpected token when deserializing object: Integer. Path 'UsefulData[0], line 4, position 5).

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15228384/2457029) post, it allready has a custom serializer that appears to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it also does what I'm needing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I was doing everything wrong with the ReadJson method.

Here's the custom JsonConverter for people with the same problema I had:

```
public class EnumerableByteConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        var result = typeof(IEnumerable<byte>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(value);
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] bytes = ((IEnumerable<byte>)value).ToArray();
            int[] ints = Array.ConvertAll(bytes, c => (int)c);

            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (int number in ints)
            {
                writer.WriteValue(number);
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<int> ints = null;
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return default;
        while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            {
                ints = new List<int>();
                reader.Read();
            }
            else if(reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Integer)
            {
                ints.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value));
                reader.Read();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
        if (ints == null)
            return default;
        else
        {
            byte[] bytes = Array.ConvertAll(ints.ToArray(), x => (byte)x);
            if (objectType == typeof(byte[]))
            {
                return bytes;
            }
            var result = new List<byte>(bytes);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```