# Why is my array serialising into a string

Tags: c#, serialization, jsonconvert

I have created the following test vector class:

```
public class TestVector
{
   public UInt16 MaxBlockSize { get; }
   public byte[] Payload { get; set; }

   public TestVector(ushort maxBlockSize, byte[] payload)
   {
      MaxBlockSize = maxBlockSize;
       Payload = payload;
   }
 }
```

In my test, I am populating a list of vectors defined as per:

```
private static HashSet<TestVector> myVectors = new HashSet<TestVector>();
```

And then serialising "myVectors" using JsonConvert and write the result to a file as per:

```
var jsonOuput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myVectors , new JsonSerializerSettings{ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace})

File.WriteAllText(@"e:\MyJson.json", jsonOuput);
```

Here is a Json typical output (with a list/Hashset composed of 2 vectors):

```
[
 {
    "MaxBlockSize": 256,
    "Payload": "bjQSAAAAAABvNBIAAAAA..."
  },
  {
    "MaxBlockSize": 256,
    "Payload": "VjQSVzQSWDQS...."
  },
 ]
```

Now what I do not get is why "Payload" is serialised as a string and not as an array.
My questions are:

1. What is this string format (ASCII code maybe?) and why is it used instead of a byte[] type of representation?
2. Is there a way to get the "Payload" byte[] to be printed in a more readable way?

Comment: What would you expect it to be an array of, exactly? And what Bytes are binary data, but JSON is a text format, so it has to convert the binary data into a textual representation. I'm pretty sure it'll be a base64 string. What "readable" representation of binary data would you want? And why would it matter? JSON isn't really intended for human consumption. As long as you can deserialise it again (which you can) then it's irrelevant.

Comment: Usually, when I serialise an object, I get the actually values composing the array, not a string. eg. When I have a double[], I get a list of doubles.

Comment: That's because doubles can be directly represented in a text format (i.e. the written representation of a number). I guess the other way for your byte array could be a big strings of 0s and 1s but, would that really help you? What were you hoping to see, exactly? Also see my edit to the comment above, the bit about JSON not being intended to be read by humans. Same applies to raw binary data, for that matter.

Comment: @ADyson, the problem is that I need to do a sanity check compare of these vectors by eye against actual byte arrays. These strings are unreadable. But I get your point, thanks

Comment: @Sinatr - Looking into it, looks relevant! Thanks!

Comment: "do a sanity check compare of these vectors by eye"..in what format? If this binary array in your code contains something which you could output into a readable text format, then perhaps it begs the question why you don't store it in a similarly structured form in your code to begin with (e.g. an array of numbers or whatever it happens to be). Maybe I have missed something.

Comment: @ADyson They are just arrays of bytes. I want to be able to see in debug mode what these bytes are and compare them against what is in the file

Comment: You seem to be missing the point that "arrays of bytes" have no intrinsic text representation. What _exactly_ are you expecting to see in the file, to allow you to make the comparison?

Comment: "I want to be able to see in debug mode what these bytes are and compare them against what is in the file "..why, do you think there's a bug in the JSON serialiser or something? It's unclear what differences you think there could be, or how they could get there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15228384/7565574 describes how to configure NewtonSoft JSON to serialize byte arrays like any other arrays.

Comment: @ADyson. I get what you are saying. But I was hopping for a work around so that what is printed in my Json is split on the byte boundary (eg. 0x12, 0x56, etc)

Comment: Well I think the links that people have provided can probably do something like that for you, or at least set you on the right path. But they will simply serialise exactly what is in the byte arrays. You can sit and compare them by hand if you want to check that the serialisation worked correctly, but I can't see how it would tell you anything else useful - it's not obvious why you want to "compare" them.

Answer (score 2):

> What is this string format (ASCII code maybe?) and why is it used instead of a byte[] type of representation?

See [json.Net documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm) for primitive types:

> Byte[]  String (base 64 encoded)

So the format is base64. This is probably used since it is a reasonably efficient encoding of binary data, encoding 6 bits per character. Encoding values as an array would use much more space.

It is somewhat common to encode images or similar chunks of data as byte arrays. Since these can be large it is useful to keep the size down as much as possible.

> Is there a way to get the "Payload" byte[] to be printed in a more readable way?

There are various base64 converters online that can convert it to hex, oct, string, or whatever format you prefer to view your binary data in. But for many applications it is not very useful since the binary data often represents something that is already serialized in some way.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it makes sense!